# Extracting data from densityplot within lattice and r

Tags: r, extract, histogram, lattice, kernel-density

In R and using Lattice, I am trying to extract histogram and densityplot data by year for use by other programs.  I have the histogram part working so far:

```
library(lattice)

x <- round(runif(1000, 1999.5, 2012.5))
y <- rlnorm(1000, meanlog = log(40000), sdlog = log(40000) - log(33000)) 
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
data$y <- data$y + 2000*(data$x-2000)

GenerateBinComputations <- function(x, breaks, equal.widths=TRUE, type="percent", nint,...) { hist(x, breaks = breaks, plot = FALSE) }

a <- histogram(~data$y | data$x, type="percent", nint=101, endpoints=c(-500, 100500), equal.widths = TRUE)
results <- data.frame(seq(0, 100000, 1000))
colnames(results)[1] <- "Midpoint"
for (index in 1:13) {
    b <- trellis.panelArgs(a, index)
    b$breaks <- seq(-500, 100500, by=1000)
    c <- do.call(GenerateBinComputations, b)
    results <- cbind(results, c$density)
    colnames(results)[index+1] <- index + 1999
}

print(results)
```

Now, the question is how to do this with densityplot.  I assume it would be something similar, but I'm having problems with breaks (they are not included in the densityplot trellis object) and with finding the right object within the densityplot trellis object to use to generate the densities/percentiles for the bins.  Here is what I have so far:

```
d <- densityplot(~data$y | data$x, type="percent", nint=101, endpoints=c(-500, 100500))
```

Is there a different location in the densityplot trellis I should be referencing? Or do I have to use the density function directly, such as something like this?

```
density.estimate      <- density(data$y, n = 512 * 8)
density.interpolation <- approxfun(x = density.estimate$x, y = density.estimate$y)
density.results       <- within(data, Density <- density.interpolation(y))
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Please make an effort to make your example reproducible and minimal (or at least provide images of what you have and what you'd like)!! And remember -- we don't have your `data`, which makes the code above mighty hard to follow...

Comment: Ah, new to the site, and now I know why everyone has the randint/uniform/lognormal lines at the beginning of their sample code.  Is this more like it?

Comment: I appreciate the work you've put into greatly improving this question. Thanks for that! I don't have time to delve into this myself, but if I did, I'd start by examining the code in `panel.densityplot`. It appears to perform density calculations 'on-the-fly', such that they're not stored anywhere after plotting. You could either model your own `density()` call after that in `panel.densityplot`, or (more advanced and not necessarily better) insert debugging code that reports out the value of `h` just after it's been computed. Best of luck!